# Извлекать из строки тэги a - php

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения, строки, link

Как извлекать из строки все тэги `<a>` через `php`?
Есть например вот такая строка:

```
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor <a href='http://lorem.com' title="ipsum" class='test'>sit</a> long text. The <a href="http://earth.com">planet</a> is <b>big</b>.</div>
```

Идеальный результат был бы таким:

```
Array [
  0 => "<a href='http://lorem.com' title="ipsum" class='test'>sit</a>",
  1 => "<a href='http://earth.com'>planet</a>"
]
```

Пробовал через [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php) но получается не очень хорошо, а регулярные выражения нехорошо знаю.

Comment: Идеально будет применить нормальный html-парсер

Comment: хорошо, попробую через парсер

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вашего случая подойдет так:

```
$text = "<div>Lorem ipsum dolor <a href='http://lorem.com' title=\"ipsum\" class='test'>sit</a> long text. The <a href=\"http://earth.com\">planet</a> is <b>big</b>.</div>";

$out = array(); 
preg_match_all('|<a.* href=.*>.*</a>|U', $text, $out);

var_dump($out[0]);
```

Можно еще кучу наворотов придумать, но это вы сами. Направление мы вам дали

Comment: спасибо, как раз то что нужно, а я почти уже парсер дописал, но буду использовать Ваш вариант, по нагрузкам - лучше чем парсер

Answer (score 1):

Кому будет полезно, можете и через парсер это решить:

```
    try {
        $html = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($string);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $html = '<div class="wrapperCode">'.$string.'</div>';
        $html = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($html);
    }
    $links = [];
    foreach ($html->find('a') AS $key => $value) {
        $value = pq($value);
        $links[] = [
            'content' => $value->html(),
            'href' => $value->attr('href'),
            'title' => $value->attr('title'),
            'class' => $value->attr('class'),
        ];
    }
```

использовал [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/archive/p/phpquery/)